# Insert multiple tab-delimited text files into MySQL with Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create a program that takes a number of tab delaminated text files, and works through them one at a time entering the data they hold into a MySQL database. There are several text files, like movies.txt which looks like this:

```
1   Avatar
3   Iron Man
3   Star Trek
```

and actors.txt that looks the same etc. Each text file has upwards of one hundred entries each with an id and corresponding value as seen above. I have found a number of code examples on this site and others but I can't quite get my head around how to implement them in this situation.

So far my code looks something like this ...

```
import MySQLdb

database_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='')

cursor = database_connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE library')

cursor.execute('USE library')

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE popularity (
                    PersonNumber INT,
                    Category VARCHAR(25),
                    Value VARCHAR(60),
                    )
                    ''')

def data_entry(categories):
```

Everytime i try to get the other code I have found working with this I just get lost completely. Hopeing someone can help me out by either showing me what I need to do or pointing me in the direction of some more information.

Examples of the code I have been trying to adapt to my situation are:

```
import MySQLdb, csv, sys
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",user = "usr", passwd = "pass",db = "databasename")
c = conn.cursor()
csv_data=csv.reader(file("a.txt"))
for row in csv_data:
print row
c.execute("INSERT INTO a (first, last) VALUES (%s, %s), row")
c.commit()
c.close()
```

and:

[Python File Read + Write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928918/python-file-read-write)

Comment: Try moving the **"** in your second example so that row is passed to the execute call.

    c.execute("INSERT INTO a (first, last) VALUES (%s, %s)", row)



This link has a couple execute examples.

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#connection-objects

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can read TSV files directly using the `mysqlimport` utility or by executing the `LOAD DATA INFILE` SQL command.  This will be faster than processing the file in python and inserting it, but you may want to learn how to do both.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Ok so this really helped. I am learning Python more than SQL so I would like to do it with python even if it is slower. What I now have is cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'movies.txt' INTO TABLE popularity FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'") which is sort of working. I get the data in but not without removing Category VARCHAR(25) which I actually need. I need someway to populate Category with the names of the files i.e. movies, tv etc so that this will work. I know it must be obvious what I need to do but I can't get work i out. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Put your Category column last: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'movies.txt' INTO TABLE popularity FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n` (PersonNumber, Category, Value) SET Category='Movies'` will set the Category for each row.